# Need to implement a grid in android

Tags: java, android

I need to implement a grid that will show the position of some physical objects. I want to interact with the objects: I want to be able to send commands or request their "health" status (the objects happen to be sensor nodes).

The size of the grid is given by the user but is always square (`width=length=a`).

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Creation of a custom view might be an option. If so share your thoughts on this.

The grid that I am talking about should look like this 
http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_NWSHay-_Gtk/R8hsDLaG9XI/AAAAAAAAAKU/DO6Ltp8v7zY/s1600-h/grid.gif
where my objects are expected to be situated in the nodes of the grid.

Comment: Have you investigated the [relative layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) or a [table layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html). Either may suit your needs. Are you forming your view in XML or programmatically?

Comment: I can do both, but prefer doing it declaratively.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a [**`GridView`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html).

[**`GridLayout`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) might work too... but it is only supported by API 14 and above.